# How can I use mutliple select dropdown filters for jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables, dropdown

In my jquery datatable I want to use dropdown filters with multiple select option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

As you see in this example...

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select

... I can filter the column Office for example by Tokyo OR by London.
But I need to have the opportunity to show all entries that have the office Tokyo AND London.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://live.datatables.net/bixikujo/1/edit

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY: 200,
            initComplete: function () {
            count = 0;
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var title = this.header();
                //replace spaces with dashes
                title = $(title).html().replace(/[\W]/g, '-');
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select id="' + title + '" class="select2" ></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                      //Get the "text" property from each selected data 
                      //regex escape the value and store in array
                      var data = $.map( $(this).select2('data'), function( value, key ) {
                        return value.text ? '^' + $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(value.text) + '$' : null;
                                 });
                      
                      //if no data selected use ""
                      if (data.length === 0) {
                        data = [""];
                      }
                      
                      //join array into string with regex or (|)
                      var val = data.join('|');
                      
                      //search for the option(s) selected
                      column
                            .search( val ? val : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
                } );
              
              //use column title as selector and placeholder
              $('#' + title).select2({
                multiple: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
                placeholder: "Select a " + title
              });
              
              //initially clear select otherwise first option is selected
              $('.select2').val(null).trigger('change');
            } );
        }
  });
} );
```